# cant boot tinycore gui

Tags: tinycore

I have an ancient machine that can only boot from floppy or CD. I purchased a TinyCore CD online and booted it, and it worked well.

I installed some extensions and got it working, but i noticed that it was tinycore version 3.2 which is very old. so i bought an external burner and burned the latest .iso for tinycore and booted it but could not get the desktop. only the command line. i also burned the latest coreplus and got the same result.

When booting it looks normal and loads extensions but then spits out:

`can't open '/opt/.tce_dir': no such file or directory`

and:

`home/tc/.wbar: file exists`

then gives a command prompt. when i enter `startx` i get:

`home/tc/.wbar: file exists`

But if i boot from the original tinycore 3.2 everything works again. also i've noticed that i can't delete files. They reappear on reboot. just trivial things like a screenshot or a txt file. Do i have to undo something from the first boot in order for newer versions to boot properly?

I tried just deleting `.wbar` but that didn't help.

It reappeared on the next reboot anyways. Is there a straight forward way to wipe everything and start fresh?

Any clues or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first tried boot code `norestore` which gave me a mouse and a black screen. so at least it did something.

then tried boot code `base` which fired it right up and works. but i have to figure out what was causing the hang up so that i can uninstall it. because if i boot from `base` every time it will always start with nothing.

the final solution was to change the backup file to `sda1/tce` because the old version was using `hda1` which is no longer the convention for hard drives as i understand it. also create a `/opt/.tce_dir` file and insert `/mnt/sda1/tce`. it only took 12 hours. so thats a relief.

maybe it helps someone in the future.